# Generate a list of item based on 2 lists?

Tags: sql, google-sheets

In Google Sheet, I have a list of name

```
+-------+
| Name  |
+-------+
| name1 |
| name2 |
| name3 |
+-------+
```

And then I have a list of attendance

```
+-------+
| Name  |
+-------+
| name1 |
| name3 |
+-------+
```

I would like to generate a list that didn't attend the event

```
+-------+
| Name  |
+-------+
| name2 |
+-------+
```

How can I generate the last table? Thanks in advance

EDIT: Since Google Sheets support query. So it is better to add SQL tag.

Comment: if you don't use Excel, don't tag with Excel. There's a difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
=FILTER(A2:A,ISNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A,B2:B,1,0)),A2:A)
```

Comment: Thought of `=FILTER(A2:A,countif(B2:B,A2:A)=0)` but `=FILTER(A2:A,ISNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A,B2:B,1,0)))` looks faster!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want? The formula shown in C2 is dragged down into C2:C4

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To generate values like you described you might want to create yourself a script `Tools -> Script editor`.

*Script:*

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var sourceColumnIndex = 0;
  var compareColumnIndex = 1;
  var setColumnIndex = 2;
  var currentSetRow = 1;

  for(var i=1; i<values.length; i++) {
    var sourceCell = values[i][sourceColumnIndex];
    var sameValues = false;

    for(var j=1; j<values.length; j++) {
      var compareCell = values[j][compareColumnIndex];

      if(sourceCell == compareCell) {
        Logger.log("\"" + sourceCell + "\"(" + i + "/" + sourceColumnIndex + ") == \"" + compareCell + "(" + j + "/" + compareColumnIndex + ")\" => true.");
        sameValues = true;
        break;
      } else { 
        Logger.log("\"" + sourceCell + "\"(" + i + "/" + sourceColumnIndex + ") == \"" + compareCell + "(" + j + "/" + compareColumnIndex + ")\" => false.");
      }
    }

    if(sameValues == false) {
      sheet.getRange(currentSetRow + 1, setColumnIndex + 1).setValue(sourceCell);
      currentSetRow++;
    }
  }
}
```

*Result before running the script:*

[image]

*Result after running the script:*

[image]